# How to make RASTER from irregular point data without interpolation

Tags: raster, r, vector-grid

I was trying to make a raster image from an irregularly spaced point database. The data looks like-

```
> head(s100_ras)
         x       y         z
1 267573.9 2633781 213.29545
2 262224.4 2633781  69.78261
3 263742.7 2633781  51.21951
4 259328.4 2633781 301.98413
5 264109.8 2633781 141.72414
6 255094.8 2633781  88.90244
```

I want these 'z' values within a mesh which I created by

```
# Create a fine mesh grid
my_mesh=expand.grid(seq(min(s100_ras$Y),max(s100_ras$Y),l=100),
                    seq(min(s100_ras$X),max(s100_ras$X),l=100))
```

I also want the z-values to be assigned as 'NA' for those mesh points that are outside the data points. The points over the mesh looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vYzlwTkhvaHBFTnc/edit?usp=sharing when I plot

```
plot(my_mesh)
points(s100_ras$Y, s100_ras$X, pch="*", col='blue')
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to build on this, the following steps don't work because my mesh grid and data points are not of the same scale!!

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
xyz<-cbind(my_mesh, s100_ras)
r <- rasterFromXYZ(xyz)
image(r)
```

If I try to make a raster just by using the data points (without any mesh), R throws an error since my data is irregularly spaced!

```
library(sp)
s100_ras <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = s100_ras$Y, y = s100_ras$X), 
                       z = as.vector(s100_ras$mean))
coordinates(s100_ras) <- ~x+y
proj4string(s100_ras) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84")
gridded(s100_ras) = TRUE

suggested tolerance minimum: 0.916421 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

Moreover, I was trying to play with 'rasterize' function (for irregular grids) of 'raster package', but couldn't get a way with it :(. I know how to interpolate and make a regular grid, but for the sake of originality, I want to AVOID interpolation. Is it possible to make a raster of irregularly spaced data points without idw or kriging methods?

Comment: The problem with irregular spaced grids is that the algorithm fails if points lie too close/far together. A (non-optimal) workaround: Why not take the minimal distance between cells and create a rectangular vector grid. Then join the average values of the points to that grid and rasterize it.

Comment: I had the same problem - the solution was to use `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` with the suggested `tolerance` argument (0.916421 in your case).

Comment: @Tomas how do you decide on the tolerance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I assume you want your irregular point data on a regular raster. In that case, rasterize should work, and the examples in ?rasterize show how.

Your example data

```
s100 <- matrix(c(267573.9, 2633781, 213.29545, 262224.4, 2633781, 69.78261, 263742.7, 2633781, 51.21951, 259328.4, 2633781, 301.98413, 264109.8, 2633781, 141.72414, 255094.8, 2633781, 88.90244),  ncol=3,  byrow=TRUE)
colnames(s100) <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

Using the "terra" package:

```
library(terra)
# set up a raster geometry, here deriving an extent from your data
e <- ext(apply(s100[,1:2], 2, range))
# set up the raster, for example
r <- rast(e, ncol=10, nrow=2)

# you need to provide a function 'fun' for when there are multiple points per cell
x <- rasterize(s100[, 1:2], r, s100[,3], fun=mean)
plot(x)
```

And with the old raster package

```
library(raster)
# set up an 'empty' raster, here via an extent object derived from your data
e <- extent(s100[,1:2])
e <- e + 1000 # add this as all y's are the same

r <- raster(e, ncol=10, nrow=2)
# or r <- raster(xmn=, xmx=,  ...

# you need to provide a function 'fun' for when there are multiple points per cell
x <- rasterize(s100[, 1:2], r, s100[,3], fun=mean)
plot(x)
```

Comment: excellent solution to the problem@Robert

Comment: Sorry can you clarify why you add e <- e + 1000 ?

Comment: @mman1123   That is just to make things work with these odd example data. All y coordinates are the same and hence the extent is zero in the y direction, so I add 1000 --- entirely arbitrary --- to be able to make a raster from the extent.

Comment: Is there a pythonic solution for this?

Comment: why in raster(e, ncol=10, nrow=2)  ncol is 10 and nrow is 2?

Comment: @yuliaUU: It is just an example

Comment: @RobertHijmans how can we do this in terra?

Comment: Now updated for terra

Comment: @RobertHijmans thanks a lot. Does rasterize automatically ignore NAs? I don't see na.rm in the function options.

Comment: No, but you can use it because there is argument "`...` additional arguments passed to fun"

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me - the solution was to use SpatialPixelsDataFrame with the suggested tolerance argument (0.916421 in your case):

```
points <- SpatialPoints(s100_ras[,c('x','y')], s100_ras[,c('z')])
pixels <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points, tolerance = 0.916421, points@data)
raster <- raster(pixels[,'z'])
```

though, due to the high tolerance value, the raster doesn't fit very well to the original points. Could be fit much better.

Comment: The first line of code has a closing bracket missing?

Comment: @Antti thanks, corrected!