# Creating and interpolating raster stack from CSV in R

Tags: raster, r, interpolation

I have a CSV of biweekly temperature values for the year 2011, at a 1000-m scale in part of the state of Iowa.  The CSV contains ~95000 rows of temperature data, with the first 2 columns as the x and y points and the subsequent 27 columns are the 14-day intervals.  I am trying to convert the CSV into a raster stack at 30-m resolution using interpolation, where each layer of the stack is a biweekly period (27 layers).  The code I am using to convert from a CSV to raster stack also uses a reference raster, which is a raster layer of the correct extent and 30-m resolution.

This code has worked for me before for smaller CSV files.

[image: preview of what the CSV looks like (the temperature values purposefully do not make sense here)]

```
pts <- read.csv("bimonthly_1000m_temp.csv")

ref = raster("~/reference_raster.tif")
u=crs(ref)

coordinates(pts)=~y+x 
proj4string(pts)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # set it to lat-long
pts = spTransform(pts,crs(u))
gridded(pts) = TRUE
r = stack(pts)
projection(r) = crs(u)
r_crop <- crop(r,ref)
extent(r_crop)=extent(ref)
r_crop_resam = resample(r_crop, ref, method='bilinear', filename = "~/interpolated_raster.tif")
```

But, I get an error at `gridded(pts) = TRUE`:

```
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.111429 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

Any suggestions?  This [answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79062/how-to-make-raster-from-irregular-point-data-without-interpolation) is in the vein of what I am looking for, though I *am* trying to interpolate and creating a raster stack.

Comment: if the points fall on a grid you should create the raster before transforming them (what is the `crs(u)`?  Try `rasterFromXYZ(pts)` directly after read.csv (before and instead ofusing the sp coordinates/gridded stuff)

Comment: Does "at a 1000-m scale" mean your points in the CSV are roughly 1000m apart? And you want to sample that up to a 30m resolution?

Comment: Thanks @mdsumner. I tried rasterFromXYZ() but got Error in rasterFromXYZ(dt) : x cell sizes are not regular.  So I think the problem must be with my pts (my CSV file itself), it seems like they do not fall on a grid.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, exactly that.

Comment: "if the points fall on a grid" - try plotting them, it's often fairly clear - use 'pch = "."' so it's fast to plot many points